# Protocol handler start failed Spring Boot SSL application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ssl, java-8

As soon as I add the SSL properties in spring boot my application does not run from command line.

Here is my properties file
    #API Settings
    server.port = 1180

```
## MULTIPART (MultipartProperties)
# Enable multipart uploads
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
# Threshold after which files are written to disk.
spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold=2KB
# Max file size.
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=200MB
# Max Request Size
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=215MB

## File Storage Properties
# All files uploaded through the REST API will be stored in this directory
file.upload-dir=D:/uploads


server.ssl.enabled=true

#Client
server.ssl.client-auth=need
server.ssl.key-store=D:\Symbox Staging Setup\SimulationAPI2waySLL\JKS\nt-ms.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=kalsym

server.ssl.key-alias=nt-ms
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS

server.ssl.trust-store=D:\Symbox Staging Setup\SimulationAPI2waySLL\JKS\nt-ms.jks
server.ssl.trust-store-password=kalsym
```

Here is my output

[image: Output]

Comment: do I have to add spring boot security??

Comment: I'd start by placing `nt-ms.jks` under `<module>\src\main\resources`. Then change the properties to `server.ssl.key-store=classpath:nt-ms.jks` and `server.ssl.trust-store=classpath:nt-ms.jks`. That would eliminate any problems related to absolute paths.

Comment: this also does not work

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58602917/8719655

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still looking for solution, this stackoverflow.com/a/58602917/8719655 works. Thanks Carlos